# Is there any API which can give me Symbolic Names for event ID for Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

Need an API in any which could give my SYMBOLIC_NAME for given Event ID's for Active Directory. Tried to search on google but couldn't find one. Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. These are an internal detail of Windows.